# Ternary operator and assignment: better way for not calling the same function twice

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, ternary-operator

I have this code line:

```
const my_v = !isNaN(parseInt(jQuery('#id').val())) ? parseInt(jQuery('#id').val()) : 0;
```

As you can see I call the `parseInt` function twice.
I was wondering if there is a way to do that assignment calling the function once.

Comment: Assign it once before you get to this line?

Comment: You right. Since I do not know the new javascript specs I was asking if there is a way to do with 1 code line.

Comment: Also, you could just use `const my_v = parseInt(jQuery('#id').val()) || 0` - no need for a conditional operator in this case.

Comment: Note that you also call the `jQuery('#id')` and `val()` functions twice.

Comment: You *could* do it in the same line but it's not worth the hassle - makes it harder to read.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result of `parseInt()` is going to be either a number or `NaN`, so you can use `||`:

```
const my_v = parseInt(jQuery("#id").val()) || 0;
```

Now, in general I would caution anyone against using `parseInt()`, because (by design) it accepts strings like "123hello world" as valid numbers (`123` in this case). You can use the `Number()` constructor or plain unary `+` to coerce a string to a number. If you don't want a fractional part, you can use `Math.floor()` or `Math.round()`, and you can check numerically to see if there's a fractional part if that should be considered an error.

Comment: Yes I realize that `NaN` is also a number; you know what I mean :)

Comment: In this case parseInt is exactly what I need. Strip characters and keep numbers.

Comment: @GiacomoM OK, it's just my standard warning because it can surprise people

Answer (score 1):

Sure using an IIFE:

```
 (n => !isNaN(n) ? n : 0)(parseInt(jQuery('#id').val()))
```

But seriously, usea local variable.

Answer (score 1):

With one `const` you can declare more than one variable.

```
const idValue = parseInt(jQuery('#id').val()), my_v = isNaN(idValue) ? 0 : idValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have already a stringed integer value, you could just take a number or zero as default value.

```
const my_v = +jQuery('#id').val() || 0;
```

If not, get first the value and then the integer part.

```
const my_v = Math.floor(+jQuery('#id').val() || 0);
```

Comment: Could yield a different result for a value like `10.a` or even `10.5`

Comment: @Rajesh, the value is already a number, then no need to parse it again.